# How does Google manage its service package installation and upgrade?

Tags: software-installation

The RPM, yum or apt tools are very popular in the Linux world, but I don't know whether Google uses these tools in their internet service management work, and use these tools to manage the service version, service rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking how they manage to update their systems without ever having down time. The answer is a fair amount of load balancing and high availability cluster (more the latter). With HA clustering, you can migrate services (including the IP addresses associated with them) between the various nodes in the cluster.

After dependent resources are migrated, the service (apache, samba, whatever) gets started on the other node, then the VIP (virtual IP) is finally migrated to the destination. So they just need to migrate whatever service is running on the node they're updating to another node, do their work, then move it back when they're done.

I don't know what HA software uses, but if you're interested in doing this yourself [Cluster Suite](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Suite_Overview/) is the only FOSS product I know of that's any good (not that I have much experience with other products).

There are other non-cluster HA solutions like [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/HighAvailability.html) you could look into as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, you answer part of my question, and also want to know whether they use RPM, apt-get like tool for their operating level work? means they need to put their software to a RPM or deb package, and use tool install it, and resolve the dependency by tool? or they develop their own tools, since i think the above tool are week for some area for offical service, for example, the support for rollback.

Comment: I'm not sure what google uses as far as a package manager, but I can't imagine they would roll their own. I'm a RHEL admin and most places I've worked have used yum without issue. Rollbacks are supported for kernels (in that it lets you keep three kernels installed in case a newer one breaks something). Tools saying they support rollback and actually supporting it are sketchy at best. Yum supports "downgrade" and I'd wager that's as close to a rollback as you can get.

Yum's actually such a good tool that Solaris 11 essentially implements the idea for their `pkg` and `pkgrepo` utilities.

Comment: Also, most enterprise environments have "development" and/or "testing" environments. "development" would be for internal solutions development and "testing" is obvious. Usually, admins are supposed to be pretty sure of what they're applying before they actually do it. Even then, they go through the test environment and verify functionality before they apply it to production. If the test environment is set up to mirror production, any issues should surface there.

Comment: thanks joel, do you think a internet application can be mananged by the yum or rpm tool? the truth is the application changed frequently, maybe one or two publish per month, if met site issue, we should apply package the same day, of course, the new package maybe not well tested, so the rollback function is very important for our product, what i descide is implementing the installation, rollback and version manangement strategy by ourself, do the  by ourself, i think this will be more flexible for our situation, and also we know what to do(maybe some workaround) if we met critical issues